# C programming: get line, 2D array and ending user input

Tags: arrays, c, string, getline

```
char* str = NULL;
size_t capacity = 0;

getline(&str, &capacity, stdin);
```

The above code is an example of using getline to dynamically allocate memory while reading a string input. But, what if I'm trying to read the input into a 2D array?

Example:

```
Linenumberone (enter)
Linenumbertwo (enter)
(enter) <<< enter on an empty line - stop reading user input
```

I do know about the function strlen, so I was thinking I could technically use that to figure out when to stop reading user input? But I'm a bit confused, is it even possible to read user input using getline into a 2D array in C as described? I've only seen people using it in C++

Comment: Either reuse the string (it will be reallocated as needed by `getline`). Or use an array of pointers (each pointer initialized to `NULL`) that you pass to `getline` in turn.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You should post it as an answer instead

Answer (score 0):

We can declare an array of pointers, then assign each line to the 2D array in a loop. See the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *line[5] = {NULL}; // array of 5 pointers
    size_t len = 0;

    int i=0;

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        getline(&line[i],&len, stdin); // reading strings
    }
    
    printf("\nThe strings are \n");
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        printf("%s",line[i]);  // prinitng the strings.
    }


    return 0;
}
```

The output is (first 5 lines are input) :

```
krishna
rachita
teja 
sindhu
sagarika

The strings are 
krishna
rachita
teja 
sindhu
sagarika
```

Comment: this answer is great, but the thing is, i don't know how many lines the user will decide to input, aka it's not a specific amount of lines, simple should end the input by inputting an empty line.

Comment: @slipper13 `malloc` and *`realloc`*?

Answer (score 0):

Each time `characters = getline(&str,...)` is used, new dynamic memory is allocated at the address `str`, with a size equal to  number of `characters` read. It suffices to store the buffer address (value of `str`) into an array at each `getline()` call. Subsequently, the buffer address (`str`) in `getline()` is incremented by the number of characters read in the last `getine()`. See code and example below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
  char *buffer=NULL;
  size_t capacity = 0;
  size_t maxlines = 100;
  char *lines[maxlines]; // pointers into the malloc buffer for each line

  printf ("Input\n\n");

  int lines_read;
  int characters;
// read getline until empty line or maxlines
  for (lines_read = 0; lines_read < maxlines; lines_read++)  {
      printf ("Enter line %d: ", lines_read + 1);
      characters = getline (&buffer, &capacity, stdin);
// stop at empty line
      if (characters == 1) break;
// convert end of line "\n" into zero (C null-terminated string convention)
      buffer[characters - 1] = 0;
// save starting location into lines
      lines[lines_read] = buffer; // save pointer to the start of  this line in the buffer
      buffer += characters;       // set  pointer to the start of a new line in the buffer
  }

  printf ("\nOutput\n\n");

  // print lines read excluding empty line
  for (int i = 0; i < lines_read; i++)
    printf ("Line[%d] = %s\n", i+1, lines[i]);

  return (0);
}
```

Example output:

```
Input

Enter line 1: This
Enter line 2: is
Enter line 3: an
Enter line 4: example.
Enter line 5: 

Output

Line[1] = This
Line[2] = is
Line[3] = an
Line[4] = example.
```